# Не подключается css

Tags: php, css, denwer

Есть 3 файла, которые лежат на денвере. Первый из них .htaccess, он лежит в корне сайта, вот его содержимое:

```
 RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

Насколько я понимаю, он делает так чтобы все запросы перенаправлялись на Index.php файл. Вот собственно сам index.php файл, он тоже находится в корне сайта :

```
<?php

    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] === '/'){
        $page = "home";
    }
    else {
        $page = substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 1);
        if(!preg_match('/^[A-z0-9]{3,15}$/',$page)){
            exit("error url");
        }
    }
    session_start();


    if(file_exists("all/$page.php")) include_once ("all/$page.php");
    elseif($_SESSION['ulogin'] === 1 and file_exists( "auth/$page.php")) include_once ("auth/$page.php");
    elseif($_SESSION['ulogin'] !==1 and file_exists( "guest/$page.php")) include_once ("guest/$page.php");
    else exit("Страница 404");



function top( $title ){

        echo '
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
        <meta charset=UTF-8>
        <title>'.$title.'</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text\css">
        </head>
        <body>
        <div class = "wrapper">
            <div class = "menu">
                Меню
            </div>
            <div class = "content">
            Контент
            </div>
        </div>';

    }

    function bottom(){
        echo "</body>
        </html>";
    }
?>
```

В нем проверяется авторизован ли пользователь и в зависимости от этого подключаются другие страницы, точнее их содержимое. В данном случае, в адресной строке браузера я пишу следующее : hostname.com/login, как и предполагалось подключается файл login.php, вот его содержимое, он лежит в папке guest, которая в корне сайта:

```
<?php
    top("Страница входа");
    bottom();
?>
```

Всё элементарно, но не подтягиваются на страницу стили, файл со стилями лежит тоже в корне сайта. Пробовал ставить инлайновые стили, они работают. Если посмотреть исходник страницы в браузере и попробовать открыть файл со стилями то он не открывается. Проблема в файле .htaccess?

Comment: Весь код создан лишь для ознакомительных целей, пытаюсь освоить php, дело в том что у человека чьи я видео уроки смотрел всё пашет...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Между вашими двумя строками в .htaccess вставьте еще эти строки:

```
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Просто у вас существующие файлы тоже под обработку * попадают

Comment: Заработало, огромное вам спасибо! Буду теперь о том что в файле .htaccess написано курить) Ещё раз спасибо.

Comment: Да не за что. На всякий случай поясню, что делают эти две строки: они сообщают, что запросы на реально существующие файлы и директории не нужно обрабатывать mod_rewrite. Для всего остального есть -MasterCard- index .*

Comment: Спасибо,  я учту)

Answer (score 0):

Замените это:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text\css">`

На это:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">`

Если не заработает добавьте слэш перед style.css.

Comment: Пробовал, не помогает. Но в любом случае спасибо.

Comment: Попробуйте удалить файл .htaccess. Скорее всего проблема заключается в нем, я не очень знаком с опытом наполнения его, но мне кажется, что все запросы идут на него, в вашем случае я думаю href обрабатывается, как index.php/style.css или что-то около того, что не является правильным и естественно соответствует пути файла стилей.